# Laravel at least one field is valid

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-8

I have an array with two relevant keys where at least one of both shall contain a valid email address.

```
$data = [
 'mail' => 'firstname.lastname#tld.com',
 'mail2' => 'firstname.lastname@tld.com',
 ...
]
```

I've tried a validation using the `exclude_with` method, which works if the `mail` field is invalid, but `mail2` is valid. However, it doesn't vice versa.

```
$validated = Validator::make($data, [
    'mail' => 'exclude_with:mail|email',
    'mail2' => 'exclude_with:mail2|email',
])->validate();
```

I could do this easily with other PHP methods or regular expressions, but I wonder if this is archivable with Laravel's validator.

The goal is to get at least one field with a valid email or fail.

## Update

Based on [Abdulla's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4595675/abdulla-nilam) promising answer, I found that even if the first email is valid but the second is not, the validation fails:

```php
$data = [
     'mail' => 'firstname.lastname@tld.com', // correct
     'mail2' => 'firstname.lastname#tld.com' // wrong
 ];

 $validator = Validator::make($data, [
     'mail' => 'exclude_unless:mail2,null|email',
     'mail2' => 'exclude_unless:mail,null|email',
 ]);
```

Output:

```
The mail2 must be a valid email address.
```

Comment: are you using laravel 8? I don't see an exclude with validation there, only exclude without

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-exclude-with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`exclude_unless()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-exclude-unless) in Laravel

It was tested with these two examples. (You can swap array positions too). And removed `->validate()` as well

1. One valid and one invalid Email (as per in the question)

   ```
    $data = [
        'mail' => 'firstname.lastname#tld.com', // wrong 
        'mail2' => 'firstname.lastname@tld.com' // correct
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($data, [
        'mail' => 'exclude_unless:mail2,null|email',
        'mail2' => 'exclude_unless:mail,null|email',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $messages = $validator->messages();
        foreach ($messages->all() as $message)
        {
            echo $message;
        }
        die();
    }
    echo "pass";
    die();
   ```

   Output was

   [image]
2. Both invalid emails

   ```
    $data = [
        'mail' => 'firstname.lastname#tld.com', // wrong 
        'mail2' => 'firstname.lastname#tld.com' // wrong 
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($data, [
        'mail' => 'exclude_unless:mail2,null|email',
        'mail2' => 'exclude_unless:mail,null|email',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $messages = $validator->messages();
        foreach ($messages->all() as $message)
        {
            echo $message;
        }
        die();
    }
    echo "pass";
    die();
   ```

   Output

   [image]

---

> customize the error message to a standard message such as **"At least one Email should be valid"**.

Comment: ahhh, I never thought to use unless with the `null` condition. Will try this right away. Many thanks!

Comment: oh, unfortunately it does not work if the last attribute has an invalid email-address in the `$data` array. In your first example, swap the wrong/correct and you'll see.